# error C2039: "Vector": Is no Element of "Eigen"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, eigen3

the following code snippet works perfectly on wsl with C++14 and g++.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
   Eigen::Vector<double,12> a; //does not work on MSVS
   return 0;
}
```

However, if I want to compile it on Windows10 with MSVS15 and its Compiler cl I get an error message.

> Main.cpp(5): error C2039: "Vector": Is not a Element of "Eigen"
> c:\dev\eigen-3.3.7\eigen\src/IterativeLinearSolvers/IncompleteCholesky.h(17):
> note: See Deklaration of "Eigen"
> Main.cpp(5): error C2065: "Vector": non-declared Identifier
> Main.cpp(5): error C2062: "double"-Typ unexpected

Does somebody know why this error message occurs on Windwos whereas with g++ itworks?

However, the following works:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,12,1> b;
Eigen::Vector2d c;
Eigen::Vector3d d;
```

Including the headerfile mentioned in the error message do not change the output.

Moreover, is somewhere in the Internet a comparison between g++ and cl in terms of coding?

Answer (score 1):

Same error exists in version 3.3.9 with VS2019. But it seems that version 3.4-rc1 solved this problem.